# Opposite of a rhetorical question

Tags: adjectives, questions

I understand a 'rhetorical question' to be a question that was asked for the purpose of rhetoric, such that the asker was not expecting or interested in a response.

When I think of the concept of a question in general I normally think of a statement that invites an answer in response. So to me the most commonly occuring concept which 'question' refers to is in a sense opposite to the concept of 'rhetorical question'. Then outside of the context of rhetorical questions, I understand 'question' to mean 'non-rhetorical question'.

Is there an adjective I can put in front of 'question' to specify that I mean a non-rhetorical question? I could then use this when rhetorical questions are being discussed and it's no longer clear from the context that the word 'question' means 'non-rhetorical question'.

I would be interested to hear different suggestions for this, as well as thoughts on how appropriate 'dialectical question' could be to try to convey this meaning.

Comment: Hilarious.  Normally you wouldn't feel the need to clarify.  If anything, people err on the side of mistaking rhetorical questions for real ones.  Maybe "real"?  "Actual"?

Comment: "Question" is enough.  Unmodified, a question is a question.

Comment: Do you mean "an earnest question"?

Comment: Questions can have multiple tones: they can be rhetorical, non-rhetorical, clever, dumb, pointed, loaded, etc. It's impossible to tell which one you're looking for unless you add an example sentence wherein to use the word.

Comment: 'Earnest question' is great, thanks @Gary

Comment: ["Earnest"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/earnest) implies intensity or gravity.

Comment: @Joe "Is there an adjective I can put in front of 'question' to specify that I mean a non-rhetorical question?" Earnest does not answer this question. It answers "how do I convey that a question is grave and heartfelt?"

Comment: A "rhetorical question" is a question,so using "question" alone is better than without, but it still leaves a little ambiguity. And it sounds weird saying "this is a question". If there's some suspicion that the question may be perceived as rhetorical, then "this is a non-rhetorical question" is simply the perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

"non-rhetorical" is the word you are looking for. This wouldn't be used except in an instance where the question might be mistaken for rhetorical.

"Can you image something better than this?" You might ask this looking for answers, but most people would probably mistake this for rhetorical. You could clarify by saying "The question is non-rhetorical."

Comment: Absolutely, single-word questions on this site often include the actual answer in the description of the problem as this one does. Sometimes people over-think things.

Comment: I thought it was clear that I had already considered 'non-rhetorical' and decided that it wasn't what I was looking for, given that I used it in the question. Next time I will state that explicitly.

Comment: @Joe Sometimes the answer is not the answer we expect.

Comment: In this case, the answer I was looking for was 'earnest' and not 'non-rhetorical'.

Comment: @Joe "this is an earnest question" doesn't directly negate it being rhetorical. You could arguably be being earnest about being rhetorical. Also, it must be long winded to use that in a sentence. What about "genuine question"? But as has been stated in the comments and this answer, the most direct is "non-rhetorical question". It's precise and has no ambiguity at all.